# FindBugs 3.0.1 плагин не виден в Eclipse Mars (стоит JRE 1.8)

Tags: eclipse, java

Плагин установился корректно, но не всплывает ни в контекстном меню, ни в настройках. В интернетах пишут, что конфликт с версией 1.8, но разработчики говорят о том, что с версии jre 1.7 и выше должен работать.
Каким-то непонятным мне образом надо заставить FindBugs искать ошибочки...